# ASP.NET MVC URL Route Mapping (URL rewriting) Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, routes, global-asax

Here is my .Net MVC Folder structure:

[image: screenshot]

I have a separate Folder called “Area” and inside that I have a Folder called “Restaurant”.
Inside this “Restaurant” Folder I have a controller Called “MenuController” which has action named “Index”

I am tried to rewrite the (Custom Route Mapping) url inside “Global.asax.cs” using following code.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "RestaurantMenu", // Route name
                "Restaurant/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "/Restaurant/Menu", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                // Parameter defaults
                );
```

But it gave me a HTTP 404 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller parameter inside your route should be the name of the controller, not the path :

If your controller name is `Menu` then, change it to this way :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "RestaurantMenu", // Route name
    "Restaurant/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Menu", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    // Parameter defaults
);
```

And the another strange thing is that : is this route sitting inside your Global.asax file? It should be inside your RestaurantAreaRegistration.cs file as follows;

```
public class RestaurantAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration {

    public override string AreaName {
        get {
            return "Restaurant";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) {

        context.MapRoute(
              "RestaurantMenu", // Route name
              "Restaurant/{id}", // URL with parameters
              new { controller = "Menu", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
             // Parameter defaults
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            "Accommodation_default",
            "accomm/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

then you can give this a shot. If you would like to use ActionLink with this route, use it like that :

```
@Html.ActionLink("MyLink", "Index", "Menu", new { id = 1, Area = "Restaurant"})
```

I have written the above code with notepad so there might be some typos :)